# How to pass argument to ASMX in angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I need to pass an id and get the related questions. 
Error message - POST http://localhost:51949/API.asmx/GetAllQuestions/0 - 500 (Internal Server Error)

The web service works fine as I have checked in other part of C# code. Now, trying to access it from angularjs. Is this the right way?

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('virtualApp', []);
```

**controller.js:**

```
app.controller("virtualController", function ($scope, DataFactory) {
$scope.categories=[];
$scope.GetAllQuestions = function (categoryId) {
        DataFactory.GetAllQuestions(categoryId)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.categories = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        });
    }

$scope.GetAllQuestions(0); //to fire at page load
});
```

**services.js:**
**EDIT**

```
    app.factory("DataFactory",function ($http) {

        var urlBase = "http://localhost:51949/API.asmx/";
          var dataFactory = {};

          dataFactory.GetAllQuestionCategories = function (categoryId) {

        return $http.post(urlBase + "GetAllQuestions", { categoryId: categoryId })
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {          
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {          
  });
    return dataFactory;
        });
```

Comment: And when you debug your web service to see why you get an exception, what is that exception?

Comment: It doesnt hit the debug point in web service

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with you code is you are passing id as part of url instead of it pass id in data of ajax request

Dont pass data in url like as below

```
//do not attach categoryId
urlBase + "GetAllQuestions/" + categoryId
```

instead of it pass data in data parameter of request like as below code

```
data: { test: 'test' }
```

and url will be `urlBase + "GetAllQuestions`

---

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' },
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

one more thing you are calling function to get data than make use of `Get` method instead of `Post` method.

Comment: There is a way to pass the argument directly instead of 'req'...right?

Comment: I did this: `return $http.get(urlBase + "GetAllQuestions", { categoryId: categoryId });`

Comment: @Qwerty - yes there is way ..that is pass data in querystring and make use of Get request instead of POST  Example : urlBase + "GetAllQuestions?categoryId=" + categoryId

Comment: tried ur way. but gives an error - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=objCategory%20in%20categories&p1=string:%22&p2=%22%5C%22%22

Comment: @Qwerty - try like this as given in doc for making request https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http will help you

Comment: Error - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:51949/API.asmx/GetAllQuestions. Invalid HTTP status code 500